# how to invoke the function inside context ="module" in svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component

```
<script context="module">
export async function preload({params}){
const {name}=params;
return {name};
}
</script>
<script>
import { onMount, afterUpdate } from "svelte";
export let name;
onMount(async=()=>{
 console.log(name);
 })
</script>
```

I am new in svelte .I was working on the existing code .
For that in console giving `undefined`.
Can some one explain me how preload atoumatically called ?
And why is not working in the given code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `load` instead of `preload`,
And return in

```js
return { props: { name } }
```